# Show that $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{z-tx_i}{z-x_i}=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(1-t)x_i}{z-x_i}\prod_{\substack{j\ne i,\\j\in [n]}}\frac{x_i-tx_j}{x_i-x_j}.$

Tags: combinatorics, induction, generating-functions, symmetric-functions

Let $x_1,...,x_n,t,z$ are independent indeterminants over the ring of integer $\mathbb Z$, how to prove that:

> $$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{z-tx_i}{z-x_i}=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(1-t)x_i}{z-x_i}\prod_{\substack{j\ne i,\\j\in [n]}}\frac{x_i-tx_j}{x_i-x_j}.$$

This identity is from page 210 of Macdonald's book: *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials*. I have tried to use induction but no luck after hours of computation. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use partial fractions. Suppose there are $\alpha _i(z)$ such that
$$LHS=\sum _{i=1}^n\frac{\alpha _i(z)}{z-x_i},$$
notice that the numerator is $$\sum _{i=1}^n\alpha _i(z)\prod _{j\neq i}(z-x_i).$$
Equate numerators and evaluate at $z=x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n.$